# Broadcasting element wise multiplication in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting

I have a tensor in pytorch with size `torch.Size([1443747, 128])`. Let's name it tensor `A`. In this tensor, 128 represents a batch size. I have another 1D tensor with size `torch.Size([1443747])`. Let's call it `B`. I want to do element wise multiplication of B with A, such that B is multiplied with all 128 columns of tensor `A` (obviously in an element wise manner). In other words, I want to broadcast the element wise multiplication along `dimension=1`.
How can I achieve this in pytorch?

It I didn't have a batch size involved in the tensor A (`batch size = 1`), then normal `*` operator would do the multiplication easily. `A*B` then would have generated resultant tensor of size `torch.Size([1443747])`. However, I don't understand why pytorch is not broadcasting the tensor multiplication along dimension 1? Is there any way to do this?

What I want is, `B` should be multiplied with all 128 columns of `A` in an element wise manner. So, the resultant tensors' size would be `torch.Size([1443747, 128])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimensions should match, it should work if you transpose A or unsqueeze B:

```
C = A.transpose(1,0) * B    # shape: [128, 1443747]
```

or

```
C = A * B.unsqueeze(dim=1)  # shape: [1443747, 128]
```

Note that the shapes of the two solutions are different.

Comment: Looks like it worked. What I though was the shapes of B and A are matching along the dimension 0, so , `B*A` should have worked.

Comment: The order of the multiplication does not affect the result! (unless you do proper matrix multiplication B @ A ). The broadcasting actually works starting from the last dimension.